# how to connect remote sql server database using appc protocols

Tags: sql-server

i have a excel sheet with vba programming done that connects to the server.the details of the connection string already available in a vba form that opens when we click on a button on excel and its uses tcp/ip and appc protocols to connect to the server.
i am trying those credentials using sql server mgmt studio with tcp/ip protocols but pre-login handshake error.i assume that the user id and pwd may not be the right one as i have no information about their existing database.the third party that deals with this application only said that we can connect to their database using appc protocols .
have no information about appc.
any help appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your questions and add connection strings and error.

Comment: How are SQL Server and appc protocol related to each other? Are you sure you're not connecting to DB2? Sounds like an IBM protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Advanced_Program-to-Program_Communication

Comment: Your APPC stuff, even if it is using odbc, is also relying on a bunch of very specific libraries and machine configurations.   You are in the .01% case and any online instructions or hints about connection strings are wrong in your narrow specific case.    If you know it works on one machine but  not others then think about 3rd party libraries and very specific settings for your environment.

Comment: I need to use appc protocols to connect to the database sql server for which i need to install sna server client.But i am not able to draw a clear picture on this.any help appreciated.